# Select first char up to first non camelCase or non upper case char or up to first snake case _ in vim

Tags: vim, vi

I used this map:

`map ,w v/\([^ a-z0-9]\|[^ A-Z0-9]\)*<cr>h`

the idea is to select

in the words

```
mysuperTest
MYSUPER_TEST
mysuper_test
```

to always select the part that says mysuper

but it doesnt work, not sure why

Answer (score 3):

I would use something like the below:

```
nnoremap ,w v/\C\%#.\([a-z]\+\<bar>[A-Z]\+\)\zs<cr>h
```

One point to notice is that in a mapping you need to use `<bar>` (or escape `|` with an extra backslash) since otherwise `|` is recognized as a command separator (see `:help map-bar`.)

Another one to notice is that you want the match to *start* at the first character outside the word (so you'll land at the end of the word with the `h`). The visual selection will expand to the *start* of the match in a search. I suggest using `\zs` to set the start of the match explicitly (see `:help /\zs`.)

Finally, beware of `'ignorecase'` or `'smartcase'` settings. Use `\C` to explicitly request a case-sensitive match (see `:help /\C`.)

I also like the idea of using a stronger anchor for the start of the match, so I'm using `\%#` to match the current cursor position (see `:help /\%#`), so you're always sure to match the current word only and not end up wandering through the buffer.

Putting it all together:

```
\C         Case-sensitive search
\%#        From cursor position
.          Skip first character
\(         Either one of:
  [a-z]\+  One or more lowercase letters
  \|       (\<bar>) Or:
  [A-Z]\+  One or more uppercase letters
\)         End group
\zs        Set match position here
```

I'm skipping the first character under the cursor, since in a CamelCase word, the first character won't match capitalization of the remainder of the word.

I kept your original idea of finding the first character *after* the word then using `h` to go back one to the left. But that might be a problem if, for example, the word is at the end of the line.

You can actually match the last character of the word instead with something like `[a-z]\+\zs[a-z]`, which will set the start of the match on the last lowercase character. You can do this for both sides of the group (you can have more than one `\zs` in your pattern, last wins.) If you structure your match that way, you won't need the final `h` to go back.

I didn't handle numbers, I'll leave those as an exercise to the reader.

Finally, consider there are quite a few corner cases that can make such a mapping quite tricky to get right. Rather than coming up with your own, why not look at plug-ins which add support for handling CamelCase words that have been battle-tested and will cover use cases a lot more advanced than the simple expression you're using here?

There's the excellent [vim-scripts/camelcasemotion](https://github.com/vim-scripts/camelcasemotion) by Ingo Karkat which sets up a `,w` mapping to move to the start of the next CamelCase word, but also `i,w` to select the current one. You can use powerful combinations such as `v3i,w` to visually select the current and next two CamelCase words.

You might also check Tim Pope's [tpope/vim-abolish](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish) which, among other features, defines a set of `cr` mappings to do coercion from camelCase to MixedCase, snake_case, UPPER_CASE, etc. (Not directly about selecting them, but still related and you might find it useful.)

Comment: wow what an answer... btw: I'm using ideavim so I dont think these plugins can be added to my IDE

Comment: hm, don't know what to tell you, doesn't work for me in ideavim... not sure why. `nnoremap ,w v/\C\%#.\([a-z]\+\|[A-Z]\+\)\zs<cr>h` when applying it to ` mybippoTestisFUN` it selects only 'm' and the space in front of the word. I tried as well using \<bar>

Comment: @Toskan Unfortunately I haven't really used ideavim, so hard for me to help further there... I know it's not exactly Vim and generally more restricted, but I don't really know how much different or where it's different... Does it support `\zs`? Maybe ask a question specifically on CamelCase on ideavim, you might get answers on ideavim plugins that might work for you...

Comment: is there maybe a way I can debug the regex? like if I enter command mode? because if I edit my vimrc I have to restart my entire IDE to try out "does it work now" is there maybe a regex search replace or whatever, that I can use your exact syntax to test?

Comment: @Toskan Just try using a search with the `/` command. If you can enable `'incsearch'` and `'hlsearch'`, that might help. From the explanation above, think of which character you're looking for. It's possible that ideavim doesn't support some of the anchors, such as `\%#` for the current cursor position... Again, fairly easy to test it with a simple `/` search.